# Why do I receive an error when I consult data in my Micronaut Gorm application?

Tags: grails-orm, micronaut

I have a simple application in Mironaut with three entities, Customer, Contact and Loans.
Customer has a 1 to many relationship with Contact and Loans. I test with Grails / Gorm and it works fine.

I have a DataLoader class that works well and creates all entities with their relationships.

/****** Contact.groovy *******/

```
package com.gnc.demo.domain

import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Contact {
    Long id
    Long version

    Customer customer
    static belongsTo = Customer


    String email
    String phone
    String cellPhone
    String address
}
```

/****** Customer.groovy *******/

```
package com.gnc.demo.domain
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Customer {
    Long id
    Long version
    String driverId
    String name
    String lastName

    static hasMany = [contacts: Contact, loans: Loan]
    static constraints = {
        contacts nullable: true
        loans nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
       contacts lazy: false
        loans lazy: false
    }
}
```

/****** Loan.groovy *******/

```
package com.gnc.demo.domain

import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Loan {
    Long id
    Long version

    Customer customer
    static belongsTo = Customer

    BigDecimal amount
    long term
    BigDecimal rate

}
```

/******* CustomerController.groovy *******/

```
 package com.gnc.demo.controllers
 
 
 import com.gnc.demo.domain.Customer
 
 import com.gnc.demo.services.ContactService
 import com.gnc.demo.services.CustomerService
 import com.gnc.demo.services.LoanService
 import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
 import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
 
 import org.slf4j.Logger
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 
 
 @Controller("/customer")
 class CustomerController {
     private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);
 
 
     final CustomerService customerService
     final LoanService loanService
     final ContactService contactService
 
     CustomerController(CustomerService customerService, LoanService loanService, ContactService contactService) {
         this.customerService = customerService
         this.loanService = loanService
         this.contactService = contactService
     }
 
     @Get("/")
     String index() {
         return "Hola ! " + new Date()
     }
 
     @Get("/all/{offset}/{max}")
     List<Customer> getCustomers(String offset, String max) {
         List<Customer> customers = customerService.findAll([offset: offset, max: max])
         try {
             customers.each { customer ->
                 // LOG.info(">>> Loans   :" +customer.loans.size())
                 customer.contacts = []
                 customer.loans = []
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.info(">>> Error :" + e)
         }
 
 
         return customers
     }
 
     @Get("/{id}")
     Customer getCustomers(String id) {
         Customer customer = customerService.get(id)
         customer?.contacts = []
         customer?.loans = []
 
         customer?.contacts = contactService.findAllByCustomer(customer)
         customer?.loans = loanService.findAllByCustomer(customer)
         return customer
 
     }
 }
```

All the code is available in: https://github.com/gnpitty/com-gnc-demo

But when I test in Micronaut with my browser: http://localhost:9020/customer/10

I receive this error:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error: Error encoding object 
[com.gnc.demo.domain.Customer : 10] to JSON: could not initialize proxy - no
Session (through reference chain: com.gnc.demo.domain.Customer[\"contacts\"]-
>java.util.LinkedHashSet[0]->com.gnc.demo.domain.Contact[\"customer\"]-
>com.gnc.demo.domain.Customer_$$_jvst110_0[\"driverId\"])"}
```

Comment: I think your service methods are missing the `grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional` annotation.

Comment: If you want the entire object to be encoded as json, you need to ensure all the data is loaded in the object. The error states a proxy is attempting to be initialized, which indicates that all data is not loaded ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

As one comment said, you should make sure the @Transactional or withTransaction {} is used when reading the record.

Also, if you want to reference the proxy elements (like the Customer reference), you need to force the proxy element to be read.  I know of two ways: 1) do an eager fetch on them or 2) resolve the proxy explicitly.

I chose option 2) since I did not want to force eager fetching when it wasn't needed.  I only use this in controllers where I am return a JSON encoded domain object.  This is usually just in my REST API methods.

Example:

```
Loan.withTransaction {
  def loan = Loan.findByXYZ()
  resolveProxies(loan)   
}
```

This converts the proxies into real objects so you can access them outside of the withTransaction{} closure.  This usually is Jackson converting them to JSON.

I use this method to resolve any proxies in lists or as simple references to another domain object:

```
  /**
   * Resolves all proxies for the given domain class.  This allows the domain to be used outside of an hibernate session
   * if needed.  This will check all fields and sub-objects for proxies.
   * <p>
   * <b>Note:</b> This will usually force a read of all referenced objects.
   * @param object The object.
   */
  def resolveProxies(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
      return
    }

    for (property in object.class.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties) {
      def value = object[property.name]
      if (Collection.isAssignableFrom(property.type) && value) {
        for (item in value) {
          if (item != null) {
            // Resolved any sub-objects too.
            resolveProxies(item)
          }
        }
      } else if (value instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        // A simple reference, so unproxy it the GORM way.
        object[property.name] = value.getClass().get(value.id)
      }

    }
  }
```

Feel free to use this code anywhere you need it.